# kafka streams serilaization error: java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Byte], issue in using json data

Tags: java, apache-kafka, java-stream, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform

I am new to kafka streams and i face an issue when i try to do aggregations on json data.below is my streams code, i have copied the code and the sample input below and the error , i am using kafka version : 2.12 . I have tried few days on various implementations and now stuck at this error. error and couldn't proceed. can someone please help?

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 
 Properties props=new Properties();
 props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "bank_stream_001");
 props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
 props.put(StreamsConfig.PROCESSING_GUARANTEE_CONFIG, StreamsConfig.EXACTLY_ONCE);
 
 final Serializer<JsonNode> jsonSerialize=new JsonSerializer();
 final Deserializer<JsonNode> jsonDeserialize= new JsonDeserializer();
 final Serde<JsonNode> jsonSerd= Serdes.serdeFrom(jsonSerialize, jsonDeserialize);
 
 String inputtopic = "bank_topic1";
 String outputtopic = "bankout_topic1";
 StreamsBuilder builder =new StreamsBuilder();
 
 //stream for reading
 KStream<String,JsonNode> stream1=builder.stream(inputtopic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), jsonSerd));
 
 //create balance node for caluclations
 ObjectNode initial_balance= JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();
 initial_balance.put("count",0);
 initial_balance.put("balance", 0);
 initial_balance.put("time", Instant.ofEpochMilli(0L).toString());
 stream1.peek((k,v) -> System.out.println(k+" : "+v));
 KTable<String, JsonNode> bank_bal= stream1.groupByKey()
             .aggregate(
             () -> initial_balance,
             (key,value,cur_balance) -> newbalance(value,cur_balance)
             
         );
 
 bank_bal.toStream().peek((k,v) -> System.out.println(k+" : "+v));
 bank_bal.toStream().to(outputtopic, Produced.with(Serdes.String(), jsonSerd));
 
 KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(),props);
 streams.cleanUp();
 
 streams.start();
   System.out.println(stream1.toString());
 Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(streams::close));
}

private static JsonNode newbalance(JsonNode transaction,JsonNode balance) {
 ObjectNode newbal = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();
 newbal.put("count", balance.get("count").asInt()+1);
 newbal.put("balance", balance.get("balance").asInt()+transaction.get("amount").asInt());
 
 Long balanceEpoch= Instant.parse(balance.get("time").asText()).toEpochMilli();
 Long transEpoch =Instant.parse(transaction.get("time").asText()).toEpochMilli();
 Instant newbalanceinstant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(Math.max(balanceEpoch, transEpoch));
 newbal.put("time", newbalanceinstant.toString());
 return newbal;
 }
```

my data in topic : bank_topic1 is

```
aruna   {"name":"aruna","amount":58,"time":"2021-02-26T15:12:43.811Z"}
varun   {"name":"varun","amount":3,"time":"2021-02-26T15:12:45.081Z"}
kali    {"name":"kali","amount":16,"time":"2021-02-26T15:12:46.082Z"}
aruna   {"name":"aruna","amount":80,"time":"2021-02-26T15:13:32.806Z"}
varun   {"name":"varun","amount":33,"time":"2021-02-26T15:13:34.015Z"}
kali    {"name":"kali","amount":30,"time":"2021-02-26T15:13:35.016Z"}
```

i am getting error due to serde.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to [B at 
org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer.serialize(ByteArraySerializer.java:21)
```

can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use the overloaded version of [KGroupedStream.aggregate](https://kafka.apache.org/27/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KGroupedStream.html#aggregate-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Initializer-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Aggregator-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Materialized-) that takes a [Materialized](https://kafka.apache.org/27/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/Materialized.html) config object.  With the `Materialized` config you can provide the correct Serdes to use with the statestore.

So you can try to update your `aggregate` call to this:

```
.aggregate(
           () -> initial_balance,
           (key,value,cur_balance) -> newbalance(value,cur_balance),
           Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), jsonSerd)
   );
```

Let me know how it goes.

HTH,
Bill